# mat-radio and insert element

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have following [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/showradio-akq1bb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fradio-overview-example.html)

I was wondering how can I insert the input box right below proper radio button. So Radio 1 would have input box with text and radio 3 would have input name.  Only show depending on radio button selected. It should be a new row and not display it as part of the radio button.  The selected button moves to the middle of both the Radio button and the input.  I think it's css but i thought there might be easier way.

thanks in advance

Comment: updated the stackbliz example. Figured out the adding elements but still having issue with alignment. The Radio selected is middle of two inputs. Know how i can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modified a bit of your HTML structure, the text element should be moved out from `mat-radio-button` instead.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/showradio-vumvxf?file=src/app/radio-overview-example.html

Comment: you sir are a hero!!